# Multiple Update From PHP While Loop to SQL - White Blank Page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a while look which generates rows in a table.  These rows contain content that already exists in database and the content is in input fields.  The user can edit these input fields and when they click save I need it to edit each line in the database where the ID matches.  I have tried to put the names as an array but when I go to the UPDATE a blank white page appears.  Here is the code:

WHILE LOOP

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID,SESSION,DESCRIPTION,SESSDATE,START_TIME,EVENT_ID 
FROM b_conference_session WHERE EVENT_ID = $eventID");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$sessionName = $row['SESSION'];
$sessionDesc = $row['DESCRIPTION'];
$sessDate = $row['SESSDATE'];
$sessStart = $row['START_TIME'];

print "<tr><td valign='top'><input name='sessID[]' type='hidden' value='$sessID'>
<input type='text' value='$sessionName' name='session[]' size='15'></td>
<td valign='top'><input type='text' value='$sessionDesc' name='descr[]' size='30'></td>
<td valign='top'><input type='text' value='$sessDate' name='sessDate[]' size='15'></td>
<td valign='top'><input type='text' value='$sessStart' name='startTime[]' size='15'></td></tr>";

}
```

Then theres a submit button that posts to:

```
foreach ($_POST['sessID'] as $index => $id) {

$sql2="UPDATE b_conference_session SET SESSION = '".$_POST['session'][$index]."', 
DESCRIPTION = '".$_POST['descr'][$index]."', 
SESSDATE = '".$_POST['sessDate'][$index]."', 
START_TIME = '".$_POST['startTime'][$index]."' 
WHERE ID = '".$_POST['sessID'][$index]."";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

}
```

Nothing happens here.  Could someone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: I guess Update query's where condition is not matching. Beacuse in following code: are you getting $sessID value?
print "<tr><td valign='top'><input name='sessID[]' type='hidden' value='$sessID'>

Comment: I've printed '<input name="sessID[]" type="hidden" value="3">' which shows the correct value.

Comment: Try to `echo` your update query and check

Comment: Try this Update query
  "UPDATE b_conference_session SET SESSION = '".$_POST['session'][$index]."', 
DESCRIPTION = '".$_POST['descr'][$index]."', 
SESSDATE = '".$_POST['sessDate'][$index]."', 
START_TIME = '".$_POST['startTime'][$index]."' 
WHERE ID = '".$_POST['sessID'][$index]." ' ";

Comment: You are missing single quote for WHERE condition.

Comment: Are you getting any error. Try `ini_set("display_errors",1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Not getting any errors. Just a blank white screen

Comment: If you are getting no error then might be

1. you have not successfully posted data to your action page or doing to wrong action page
2. you are not executing the update sql statement i.e. your $sql2

Answer (score -1):

You are assuming that there is a connection between the inputs arrays and this is not necessary true. the array you are looping on on your form process script `$_POST['sessID']` builds it's index according to the values it has received from the form, so if you have an element `$_POST['sessID'][1]` it is not necessary the first checkbox on your form but the first input that has been checked.

Instead of having the other inputs in a row as an array you can have them have a unique name according to their id, so doing something like this:

```
print "<tr><td valign='top'><input name='sessID[]' type='hidden' value='$sessID'>
<input type='text' value='$sessionName' name='session_$sessID' size='15'></td>
<td valign='top'><input type='text' value='$sessionDesc' name='descr_$sessID' size='30'></td>
<td valign='top'><input type='text' value='$sessDate' name='sessDate_$sessID' size='15'></td>
<td valign='top'><input type='text' value='$sessStart' name='startTime_$sessID' size='15'></td></tr>";
```

And then on your loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['sessID'] as $id) {

    $sql2="UPDATE b_conference_session SET SESSION = '".$_POST['session_'.$id]."', 
    DESCRIPTION = '".$_POST['descr_'.$id]."', 
    SESSDATE = '".$_POST['sessDate_'.$id]."', 
    START_TIME = '".$_POST['startTime_'.$id]."' 
    WHERE ID = '".$_POST['sessID_'.$id]."";
}
```

Comment: This goes through i.e. no white screen but doesn't update.  I've tried editing the where clause as ID = '".$_POST['sessID_'.$id]."' will not match the ID as there is no_ in the table.  But still no luck.

Comment: Can you try Update query directly in phpmyadmin?

Comment: can you output the queries you get and post them and try to run them directly on the DB?

Answer (score -1):

Missing single apostrophe in WHERE clause of UPDATE query. Try following query code and see.

```
 "UPDATE b_conference_session SET SESSION = '".$_POST['session'][$index]."', 
DESCRIPTION = '".$_POST['descr'][$index]."', 
SESSDATE = '".$_POST['sessDate'][$index]."', 
START_TIME = '".$_POST['startTime'][$index]."' 
WHERE ID = '".$_POST['sessID'][$index]."'";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting no error then Two possibilities.

1. You have not successfully posted data to your action page or doing to wrong action page
2. you are not executing the update sql statement i.e. your `$sql2`

See before loop (the loop in which you are writing your **update query**) if $_POST really has array of values. if it has then you must get an error or success

If you get nothing in post array then you could add a form tag around your table

```
<form method="post" action="yourphppage.php">
<table>

<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"your query here");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo  "your html.. same html as you are doing..in your question";    
}
?php>

</table>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I you already are able to post data successfully then make sure in yourpage.php

```
echo "yes reached and i have posted following data";
var_dump($_POST); //make sure you get values here

foreach ($_POST['sessID'] as $id) 
{    
    $sql2="UPDATE b_conference_session SET
    SESSION = '".$_POST['session_'.$id]."',
    DESCRIPTION = '".$_POST['descr_'.$id]."', 
    SESSDATE = '".$_POST['sessDate_'.$id]."', 
    START_TIME = '".$_POST['startTime_'.$id]."' 
    WHERE ID = ".$id;
}
```

After above **make sure** you are really executing this `@sql2` as

```
mysqli_query($con,@sql2) or die(mysql_error($conn));
```